# Why doesn't a pseudo force act on an object placed on Earth's frictionless surface due to the rotation of the Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, friction, free-body-diagram, centrifugal-force

One might expect a pseudo force to act in this case due to the Earth's rotational motion. Pseudo forces are fictitious forces that arise in non-inertial reference frames to explain observed motion. However, in this scenario, the object does not experience a pseudo force.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum

Answer (score 2):

[Foucault's pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) demonstrates just that: the nearly frictionless motion of the pendulum keeps it on a fixed plane of oscillation, which to observers moving with the earth appears to shift due to a fictitious force.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it’s at a pole, there is a centrifugal force acting on it, it’s just in equilibrium with the local level, which is a tangent to the ellipsoid, not a sphere. That is, straight down does not point to the center of the earth (see geodetic latitude).

The Coriolis force is zero because the velocity is zero.